# Dynamically return fields of variable structure in C#

Tags: c#, object, struct, typeof

I can image this problem has a relatively simple solution, which I have however been searching without success so far.

I have a couple of `structs` to save data within my program, e.g. `Data_Type1, Data_Type2`, etc. All of these structs have fields, which I would like to access dynamically, e.g. to get an array of strings with the according values and field names. So far, this is done by:

```
public string[] GetFieldsAsStringFromTypeX(object struct_type)
{
var fields = typeof(Data_TypeX).GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
    // do sth
}
```

Now the question is how to let `Data_TypeX` be determined dynamically. Something like this

```
public string[] GetFieldsAsStringFromTypeX(object struct_type)
{
var fields = typeof(struct_type).GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
    // do sth
}
```

does not work, since typeof is expecting a data type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
 struct_type.GetType().GetFields();
```

Comment: No problem. I wished downvoters would comment though :-)